# Generate random checkerboard image with a variety of colors in PHP

Tags: php, image-processing

I have the following PHP method that generates new users a profile image when they first sign up, before they upload their own. All it does is just create them a brightly colored square - something to make the interface look a little more interesting when showing a list of users without profile photos.

How could I adapt this method so it created a checkerboard of random colors? Something like this: http://krazydad.com/bestiary/thumbs/random_pixels.jpg

```
public function generate_random_image($filename, $w = 200, $h = 200, $chosen_color = NULL) {

        if(!$chosen_color) {
            $color_options = Array("#6f0247", "#FF0569", "#FFF478", "#BAFFC0", "#27DB2D", "#380470", "#9D69D6");
            $random        = rand(0,sizeof($color_options));
            $chosen_color  = $color_options[$random];       
        }

        $rgb   = self::hex2rgb($chosen_color);              
        $image = imagecreatetruecolor($w, $h);

        for($row = 1; $row <= $h; $row++) {
            for($column = 1; $column <= $w; $column++) {    

               $color = imagecolorallocate ($image, $rgb[0] , $rgb[1], $rgb[2]);

               imagesetpixel($image,$column - 1 , $row - 1, $color);
            }

            $row_count++;
        }

        $filename = APP_PATH.$filename;

        imagepng($image, $filename);

        return $chosen_color;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about you just change

```
$color = imagecolorallocate ($image, $rgb[0] , $rgb[1], $rgb[2]);
```

to

```
$color = imagecolorallocate ($image, rand(0,255), rand(0,255), rand(0,255));
```

Then, each pixel will have it's own colour. Just draw to a small image, then scale by 200% or 300% (or some other arbitrary number) and you'll get nice, big chunky pixels like the image you linked.

Answer (score 0):

While iterating through `$row`s and `$column`s you should increase step to desired pixel size and choose another color with each iteration.

example for pixel width = 20x20 :

```
    $pixel = 20;
    for($row = 0; $row <= $h / $pixel; $row++) {
        for($column = 0; $column <= $w/ $pixel; $column++) {    
           $rgb   = self::hex2rgb($color_options[rand(0,sizeof($color_options))]); 
           $color = imagecolorallocate ($image, $rgb[0] , $rgb[1], $rgb[2]);

           imagefilledrectangle(
               $image,
               $column*$pixel,
               $row*pixel,
               $column*$pixel+$pixel,
               $row*pixel+$pixel, 
               $color
           );
        }
    }
```